# Python code while building simple neural network

Tags: python

```
2*np.random.random.((3,1))-1
```

In the above syntax why we use `2*` at the starting and `-1` at the last...

Plz help me by providing a correct relavant answer

Comment: What is the question you want to be answered?

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html)

> Results are from the “continuous uniform” distribution over the stated interval. To sample Unif[a, b), b > a multiply the output of random_sample by (b-a) and add a:
>
> `(b - a) * random_sample() + a`

In other words, instead of sampling between 0 (included) and 1 (excluded), you sample here from -1 (included) to 1 (excluded). This is just arithmetic on a numpy array.

Giving in more details, the first operation in your line of code is `numpy.random.random((3, 1))`. This calls the random() function from the numpy.random library. This function takes one input which is the size of the object you want to generate. Here, you generate a numpy array that has 3 rows and one column. This array is filled with random values between 0 and 1. Then, the second operation is `2 *`. With this, each value of the array is multiplied by 2, so that all values are between 0 and 2. Finally, `-1`. Here, 1 is subtracted to all values of the array, so that your final values lie between -1 and 1.

Comment: Thaks for ur reply... as I don't have much knowledge on coding can u plz explain more clearly